# Split array of messages into conversations

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I'm building a comment/messaging system for a website, and I've ran into a problem regarding the messages.

When i go to an item i have for sale on my website, I received all the messages that is on the item. I'm allowed to see all messages, since people on the item can only message me.

The problem is splitting the messages up into conversations, as I don't want the messages mixed together.

Each message has a sender with an id referring to the user, and a receiver, also with an id.

I've tried splitting it up into subarrays with all the messages from one sender, but that doesn't include the messages I've messaged back.

```
var messages = data.reduce(function (buckets, item) {
    if (!buckets[item._sender._id]) {
        buckets[item._sender._id] = [];
    }
    buckets[item._sender._id].push(item);
    return buckets;
}, {});

$scope.messagesBucket = _.values(messages);
```

If i console log the messagesBucket it looks like this

```
[Array[x], Array[y]] // each array is a conversation
  >0: Array[z] // each conversation is array of messages, but they don't include the ones i sent, which is my problem
  >1: Array[q]
...
```

So my problem is I don't know how to split up all the messages into conversations.

Using lodash is a bonus!

Edit (Message data):

```
[
{
"_id": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ee0",
"_item": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ed9",
"content": "Det var billigt.",

"_sender": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec2",
"firstName": "Ole",
"lastName": "Wedel",
"image": "URL"
},

"_receiver": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec1",
"firstName": "Knud",
"lastName": "Larsen",
"image": "URL"
},
"__v": 0,
"timestamp": "2015-09-03T10:57:15.918Z"
},

{
"_id": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ee1",
"_item": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ed9",
"content": "Jeg vil lige tænke over det",

"_sender": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ebe",
"firstName": "Oscar",
"lastName": "Andersen",
"image": "URL"
},

"_receiver": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec1",
"firstName": "Knud",
"lastName": "Larsen",
"image": "URL"
},
"__v": 0,
"timestamp": "2015-04-14T10:57:15.918Z"
},

{
"_id": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ee3",
"_item": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ed9",
"content": "Det går nok. Jeg har også andre jeg kan sælge til.",

"_sender": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec3",
"firstName": "Troels",
"lastName": "Sørensen",
"image": "URL"
},

"_receiver": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec1",
"firstName": "Knud",
"lastName": "Larsen",
"image": "URL"
},
"__v": 0,
"timestamp": "2014-11-12T11:57:15.918Z"
},

{
"_id": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078eed",
"_item": "5602858bb1f8f5ee05078ed9",
"content": "Arh, jeg bliver nok nødt til at springe fra...",

"_sender": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec1",
"firstName": "Knud",
"lastName": "Larsen",
"image": "URL"
},

"_receiver": {
"_id": "56028589b1f8f5ee05078ec2",
"firstName": "Ole",
"lastName": "Wedel",
"image": "URL"
},
"__v": 0,
"timestamp": "2014-05-22T10:57:15.919Z"
}
]
```

Comment: Please add some sample message data, that will make things much easier for people to answer!

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your porblem. If not, please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in short, you need to group your messages by each unique sender-receiver pair. "Unique pair" means that A+B is the same as B+A; in my code I sort them so the pair is always in the same form.

This will do:

```
function groupConversations(messages) {
    return _.groupBy(messages, function(msg) {
        return _.sortBy([msg._sender._id, msg._receiver._id]).join(' ');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response, i solved it my self after some time with the following code

```
function getItemMessages() {
            api.getItemMessages($scope.item._id)
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    if (status === 200) {
                        // push all messages into seperate conversations
                        var conversations = data.reduce(function (buckets, message) {
                            // if the message is from the creator, don't add it to it's own bucket
                            if (message._sender._id === $scope.user._id) return buckets;
                            if (!buckets[message._sender._id]) {
                                buckets[message._sender._id] = [];
                            }
                            buckets[message._sender._id].push(message);
                            return buckets;
                        }, {});

                        // find the messages by the owner, and push them into the conversation it belongs to
                        var keys = _.keys(conversations);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if (data[i]._sender._id === $scope.user._id) {
                                var index = keys.indexOf(data[i]._receiver._id);
                                var key = keys[index];
                                var conversation = _.get(conversations, key);
                                conversation.push(data[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        $scope.messagesBucket = _.values(conversations);
                        if ($scope.messagesBucket.length > 0) {
                            $scope.changeCon($scope.messagesBucket[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```